# Installing the Boost binaries on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-16.04

I'm creating a docker image for a C++ application that uses Boost. I'm using a two-stage build. The second stage contains the binaries compiled in the first stage, and should be minimal.

In the first stage in `apt install libboost-all-dev` to get all the header files. How do I install just the Boost binaries in the second stage? I couldn't find the right `apt` package, although I'm sure I just missed it.